# Best ways to track application logging in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, telemetry

I have an app that consists of an api, db and web application. They all run on AWS using RDS, EB, S3, etc.
I am using Serilog to log important events at the api level and send them to my postgresql rds.
I have not yet exposed the logging in the api but i could do that and let the web app generate logs as well.
My question is what is the best way to track the large amount of data that will be generated by this telemetry? I know i want to track logins, failed logins, most api calls, etc.
And i can send that all to my postgres Logs table as structured data using Serilogs but what do i do after that? I was thinking i would use a lambda to run each night and summarize the telemetry into a report so that i could kill off some of the logs and not have them building and building. I suppose i could use aws api gateway and let them generate these stats for me as well.

I think i'm just looking for guidance and links as to what others have done for this type of issue as i'm not even really sure where to start. Any suggestions?

Comment: Custom logging groups/streams with CloudWatch? Is your question what you should be logging or how you should be logging it?

Comment: My experience with CloudWatch so far is that it is just unmanageable. logs go by so fast and are broken up at random and not searchable. I see a big market for third party consumers/catalogers of cloudwatch. almost like aws just didn't want to implement the "last mile" of logging. I think my question is both of those things.

Comment: I suggest using an ELK stack. You can search through your logs and then rotate them out to S3 every so often. https://www.elastic.co/elk-stack